# how to firebase refernce extract the id in "onCreate" or "onUpdate" triggers?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I do not want to fetch all of the values under **{id}** in **.onUpdate()** var3 is a nested object whereas var2 is single variable.
So how do I retrieve {id} from onUpdate and pass it as a parameter to customMethod which I can use it in admin.ref()?

index.ts

```
export const funcName = functions.region("someRegion").database.ref('/user/{id}/var3').onUpdate((change, context) =>{

      const originalData = <varType> change.after.val();
      const processedData = customMethod(originalData);

      if(change.after.ref.parent)
      return change.after.ref.parent.child('custom').set(processedData);
      else
      return null;
});


function customMethod(data: varType){
 return admin.database().ref('/user/{id}/var2').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
// processing stuff after storing value from var2 in a local variable
}
```

Comment: Please add some more detail on you exact goal and the structure of your Firestore database. If i may, it is difficult to understand your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working... referenced parent node and sent the reference as parameter.

```
 const originalData = <varType> change.after.val();
 const splRef = <admin.database.Reference> change.after.ref.parent
 const processedData = customMethod(originalData,splRef);
```

```
function customMethod(data: varType,dbref: admin.database.Reference){
 return admin.database().dbref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
// processing stuff after storing value from var2 in a local variable
}
```

@Renaud, thanks anyways!!